# Onesignal: Web push notification for capture user votes

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, onesignal, web-push

I am trying to implement a mechanism to push web notification to users and ask for their votes. I want to capture and store user's votes in my DB based on the feedback given.

For this purpose, I am using Onesignal's web push notification. I have managed to add a tag to each user to identify the user. So I can now send notifications to specific users. But when user clicks on the notification, I want to have the information about the notification like player-id, the actionid, notification id so that I can capture this information in my DB. I am not sure how I can get that.

Chrome and Firefox can support web push webhooks which may help, but I still don't have any solution for Safari. Can someone please suggest any alternatives or workarounds?

Thanks!

Comment: If your users are logged in on your website you don't need to pass any id with the push notification. You can identify them as normal on your website. Is there any reason why you cannot do that?

Comment: Hi collimarco, Are you suggesting using localStorage to save the user information when the user logs in to subscribe for notifications and then in the webpage that opens when user responds to the notification, read the value and use it? I guess that would work to get the information about user ID. I think I can work around having to get the other information held by OneSignal's server. Let me try it out and I'll let you know if it works.